# Using an index to read files to a list

Tags: python

I'd like to read in files line by line based on a found index after some condition.
Here's an example:

```
Cats=[]
Dogs=[]
Fish=[]


with open('Report.txt') as f:
    for index, record in enumerate(f):
            if 'Cat' in record:
                
                index=(index+1)
```

Now I have the index. Is it possible to start reading the file into a list from this index?

Comment: You've already got the `record` to start with, whats the index for?

Comment: Instead of `index=(index+1)` which doesn't make any sense for what you are trying to do, just `Cats.append(record)`. I'm not really following what you are trying to do and your code doesn't make much sense as-is, though so that's just a guess.

Comment: Is `index` the line number in which `Cat` was found?

Comment: @TalhaTayyab Yes, the index is the number which cat is  found.

Comment: @JNevill I guess my question is more so, can I start appending at the line which cat is found?  The index+1 returns the line cats is on in my doc vs a blank line.

Comment: Seeing Andreis answer helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of whether you already met the condition using a boolean value, i.e. `foundCat`. Once you meet the condition, you can set the boolean to `True`, and check if either you met the condition or if the boolean is `True`. Here's an example:

```
cats = [] # Reserve uppercase for class names
foundCat = False

with open('Report.txt') as f:
    for index, record in enumerate(f):
        if 'Cat' in record:
             foundCat = True
        if foundCat:
             cats.append(record)
```

You don't need to increment `index` as `enumerate()` already does that automatically.

Comment: Oh! This makes more sense. I thought the solution was much more complex

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this package to go directly to the line number if you know the line number

```
import linecache
  
# extracting the 5th line
particular_line = linecache.getline('Report.txt', 4)
  
# print the particular line
print(particular_line)
```